# Why is it sometimes recommended to explicitly install npm dependencies?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, eslint

Some libraries in their documentation suggest to install their dependencies explicitly. I've seen this pattern dozens of times, but I'm not sure what difference does it make. Let's take [`eslint-plugin-react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react) as an example:

```bash
npm install eslint eslint-plugin-react --save-dev
```

It lists `eslint` for explicit installation, even though it's one if the dependencies in its `package.json`:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    // ...,
    "eslint": "^3 || ^4 || ^5 || ^6 || ^7 || ^8",
    // ...
}
```

Is it - in this case - just to keep eslint-ing the project after we uninstall `eslint-plugin-react` or is there any other reason I'm not aware of?

Comment: "*It lists eslint for explicit installation, even though it's one if the dependencies in its package.json*" it's a dev dependency though...

Comment: @VLAZ what difference does it make? It's also said to install it with `--save-dev`.

Comment: If you ignore proper dependency tracking, then there is probably no difference.

Comment: @VLAZ what do you mean? I thought that dependencies of the dependencies are part of proper tracking.

Comment: Transitive dependencies are VERY HARD TO TRACK. Or, you know, properly manage. If you depend on package A which transitively depends on B, can you tell me what version of B you have? You cannot. Depends on A. Would you have any conflicts with that package? Can you keep it up to date? Can you pin it to a given version for whatever reason? No to all. Because you don't own or manage the dependency. You're left at the mercy of A and ***not*** in control of B.

Comment: @VLAZ well, if I'm about to continue using a dependency that is using another dependency, I'm still on mercy. If it stops supporting the newest version at some point, I'm stuck anyway. Also, I found that `eslint-plugin-react-hooks`, for instance, doesn't install `eslint` explicitly. Maybe that's some sort of habit.